Estimate a simple regression (homework question)
The Director of UNAM’s Student Affairs would like to investigate the relationship between the number of hours (X) students spends campaigning and the percentage of votes (Y) they end up receiving in the Student Representative Council (SRC) election.
Student Hours   Votes
A   54  9
B   31  27
C   69  11
D   35  89
E   61  29
F   23  68
G   44  63

(a) The Director uses the following regression model: Yi=β0+β1X+μi. Estimate the values for β0 and β1. (Use 2 decimal place).
β^0 =
